# Си: как и где хранить большие тексты

Tags: c

Есть программа, которая выдает пользователю рандомный текст. В роли хранения этих больших текстов я выбрал массив, например:

```
char *en_arr[10];
```

Затем начиная с 0 идет заполнение:

```
  en_arr[0] = "Now indulgence dissimilar for his thoroughly has terminated. Agreement\n\
offending commanded my an. Change wholly say why eldest period. Are\n\
projection put celebrated particular unreserved joy unsatiable its. In then\n\
dare good am rose bred or. On am in nearer square wanted. Silent sir say\n\
...";

  en_arr[1] = L"Warmly little before cousin sussex entire men set. Blessing it ladyship\n\
on sensible judgment settling outweigh. ...";
```

Затем идет `srand()` + `rand()` и функция возвращает текст под рандомным индексом массива, получается что вернулся рандомный текст. Мне кажется это решение немного некрасивое, ибо файл `texts.c` полон только этими длинными текстами. Наверное логичнее будет хранить эти большие тексты в обычном текстовом файле и релизовать чтение этого файла в буфер программы. Но я немного не понимаю как это сделать. Если я использую системный вызов `read()` то получаю всё содержимое файла, что логично, а хотелось бы конкретный текст вытащить

Например текстовый файл состоит:

```
Huge text one. Huge text one. Huge text one.
Huge text one. Huge text one. Huge text one.

Huge text two. Huge text two. Huge text two.
Huge text two. Huge text two. Huge text two.

Huge text three. ...
```

Между текстами пустая строка для разделения текстов. Программа сгенерировала число 1. Как прочитать только первый текст в буфер? Или например сгенерировалось число 3, значит читаем 3 текст в буфер, не затрагивая при этом другие тексты. Или есть какое-то другое более просто решение?

Помню что в Питоне как-то раз приходилось работать с `yml` файлами и там можно было бы сделать таким образом:

```
1:
  text
2:
  text
```

Затем генерировать рандомное число, обращаться к этому файлу, и по индексу текста получать этот текст. А в Си видимо придется придумывать что-то иначе ...

Comment: Я бы делал индексированный файл - вначале идут смещения, где начинается каждый текст, а потом уж тексты. Чтобы сразу переходить к нужному. Или бинарный файл формата - размер строки 1, ее содержимое, потом - строки 2 и так далее. Тогда проще найти нужный текст...

Comment: @Harry, спасибо за идею, обдумаю

Comment: Почему бы не хранить каждый текст в своем отдельном файле и выбирать случайный файл из каталога?

Comment: @avp, не думаю что это хорошая задумка, текстов около 15 штук, для русского и английского языка. Структура проекта будет слегка некрасивая.

Comment: @karaname, на мой взгляд как раз наоборот. Простые текстовые файлы позволяют использовать стандартные команды (grep, awk и т.п.) для каких-то простых действий в скриптах. При развитии проекта вы можете группировать эти файлы в разных каталогах, принципиально не меняя схему обработки. И т.д. и т.п. Впрочем, посмотрите на unix, возможно ваши взгляды изменятся

Comment: Я бы использовал **shared** библиотеку. *(В линуксе флаг `-fPIC`)* При точечном доступе к строкам вам будет хорошая экономия памяти. Операционка сама будет свой кеш смотреть.

Comment: Зачем так усложнять? @Антон ниже предложил хорошее решение.

Comment: Положить текст в другой файл - это никак не решение. Ничего не даёт. @eanmos

Comment: @AlexGlebe, ну тут вопрос в том, зачем вообще считывать текст в память, если его можно изначального так хранить. Зачем усложнять себе жизнь?

Comment: Всё равно программа сама уже в кеше, хоть из библиотеки хоть прямо. Наверное другой `.c` файл - это проще. @eanmos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно ещё вот так делать!

```
/* main.c */

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *text[] =
    {
        #include "text.h"
    };

    printf("%s", text[2]);
}
```

```
/* text.h */

"Now indulgence dissimilar for his thoroughly has terminated. Agreement\n\
offending commanded my an. Change wholly say why eldest period. Are\n\
projection put celebrated particular unreserved joy unsatiable its. In then\n\
dare good am rose bred or. On am in nearer square wanted. Silent sir say\n\
...",

"Warmly little before cousin sussex entire men set. Blessing it ladyship\n",

"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi ac tempor risus, ut \n\
feugiat lectus. Maecenas hendrerit metus et velit molestie, pretium mollis libero\n\
accumsan. Praesent pretium lorem ut nisi rutrum rhoncus. Cras ipsum libero, convallis vel\n\
lorem luctus, tempor bibendum turpis. Duis mauris metus, scelerisque sit amet lorem non,\n\
venenatis placerat nisi. Praesent sit amet tellus non augue euismod ornare. Etiam id ex\n\
ultricies, malesuada elit at, pharetra quam. Vivamus efficitur, ex eget blandit aliquet, lorem\n\
orci vulputate dolor, vel iaculis sem lorem ac lorem. In a malesuada ligula. Aliquam quam mi, feugiat\n\
vel mattis at, rhoncus ut massa. Curabitur aliquam rutrum nulla ac bibendum. Donec vitae nunc \n\
rutrum, dapibus diam sed, pellentesque lectus. Etiam id risus suscipit, euismod purus a, dignissim enim.\n\
Nullam pharetra pellentesque dignissim. Phasellus nibh est, vestibulum vitae fermentum quis, lobortis \n\
sollicitudin dui. Vestibulum a libero lacinia metus blandit porta vel et nunc.\n"
```